# Where is located the folder containing the apps in a Garmin device?

Tags: garmin, monkeyc

I'm looking for the folder containing the installed apps in a Garmin Forerunner device.

I'm pretty curious to know how some apps are written in monkey c language, but, connecting the device to my laptop, I didn't find anything in the dedicated app folder.

How can I do to see app source codes???

Thanks a lot for any answer.

P. S. In the Garmin sdk I read some samples, but they are not what I want

Answer (score 0):

apps in Garmin watch located in \GARMIN\APPS

if this folder empty, that you have not installed apps